# cat .git/HEAD command in Windows?

Tags: windows, git

I am trying to see where my HEAD refers to the current commit that my working copy points to and I've been searching on Google for an hour, I couldn't find anything.

what is the `cat .git/HEAD` equivalent command in windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about trying this:

```
type .git\HEAD
```

This is similar to cat in Linux/Unix.

Windows paths use backslash unlike Unix/Linux forward slash. Forward slash on windows is usually used to specify a command line argument to a program

Answer (score 1):

You are probably better off not looking at anything directly in the .git directory.

It is slightly more annoying since some forms of the command work differently if you are in detached head, but the following are safer and easier to parse typically (and also portable)

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD
git name-rev HEAD
git rev-parse HEAD
```

Symbolic ref prints out the ref if it exists, but returns error if in detached head.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

```
git diff heads/master
```